# How can i pass existing GTM-triggered FB pixel events to FaceBook Conversions API?

Tags: google-tag-manager, tracking-pixel

I have set up triggers in Google Tag Manager that in their turn triggers FaceBook pixel events. Now I want to send these Facebook pixel events to Facebook Conversions API also.

The solutions that I can find is to pass events from GTM to GTM server side and then send the events on to FaceBook CAPI.

But isn´t the whole point of using server-side events that you can track events even though the visitors decline cookies? If the visitor declines cookies, the GTM JS code won´t load and no data will be sent to the Facebook Event Manager at all.

Are there ways to solve this? (Other than programming a custom solution with Facebook business SDK API)